# Optimal Mathematica file format for numerical data

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Which is the optimal file format for storing an array of 15 million real numbers in Mathematica?
A curious thing is that I read in these numbers (by the Import command) from a .mat matlab file of about 25 MB, but if I try to write them to another .mat file (by the Export command), they take up 120 MB. Why this difference?

Comment: try binary package ".mx".  If 15million reals is 25MB it must be compressed.